# setInterval loop not working

Tags: javascript

I am creating a simple image slide with JavaScript, but when I loop through all the images, I can not reset the loop:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll(".slide-img");
var index = 0;
var time = 1000;

function reset(){
    for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
        images[i].style.display = 'none';
        images[0].style.display = 'block';
    }   
}

reset();

var looper = setInterval(function(){ 
    index++;
    images[index].style.display = 'block';

    if(index == 3){
        index = 0;
        images[index].style.display = 'block';
        //or calling reset() again.
    }

}, 1000);
```

After setting all the image `display:none`except the first one, I tried calling `setInterval` for looping all my images, but problem occurs when the index is 3. I am calling the `reset()` function and it is not working?

Comment: `if(index = 3)` should be `if(index == 3)`.

Comment: `if(index = 3){` this code is always truthy, and always sets index to 3, ... you need to use `==` or `===` to test for equality ...

Comment: sorry i miss typing a "=" on the if statement but by setting index = 0 after that, the loop still not reset...could you tell me more about this?

Comment: If there are 3 elements, then your `<= 3` condition should be `< 3`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few problems.

- The code inside the if statement doesn't reset all the images to hidden. So you would need to call reset function instead
- Your reset function doesn't reset the index.
- You should set index 0 to block once, and then loop through the rest instead of setting index 0 to block in each iteration.
- Because you reset when index == 3, you will never see the last image. You should reset on the following iteration to ensure that each image is visible for one second.

See my example below.

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll(".slide-img");
var index = 0;
var time = 1000;

function reset(){
  index = 0;
  images[0].style.display = 'block';
  for(var i = 1; i < images.length; i++){
    images[i].style.display = 'none';
  }   
}

reset();

setInterval(function(){ 
  index++;
  if(index >= images.length){
    reset();
  } else {
   images[index].style.display = 'block';
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.slide-img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slide-img" style="background: red"></div>
  <div class="slide-img" style="background: blue"></div>
  <div class="slide-img" style="background: green"></div>
  <div class="slide-img" style="background: purple"></div>
</div>
```

If you have other question on why my code is different than yours, ask in the comments. But I think the code should be clear and understandable.